# how to insert json array into mysql using .net core

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, asp.net-core

I need to insert this json array data to MYSQL database. But I getting this `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestAPI1.Models.." `` message in the database column, how do I fix this one

This my model class

```cs
{
    public class ResultDt
    {
        public string StID { get; set; }
        public List<SubjectsDt> StudentResults { get; set; }
        public string ExamYear { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubjectsDt
    {
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        public string SubjectMark { get; set; }
    }


}
```

This is the controller

```cs
 [HttpPost("results")]
    public string AddResults(ResultDt results)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO result_details(StID, StudentResults, ExamYear) VALUES (@StID,@StudentResults,@ExamYear)";

        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection");

        using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {

            using (MySqlCommand mycommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
            {
                mycon.Open();
                mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StID", results.StID);
                mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentResults", results.StudentResults);
                mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExamYear", results.ExamYear);

                int RowsAffected = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

               if (RowsAffected == 0)
                {
                    return "ERROR - Check The Inputs";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Results Details Succesfully Added";
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

This is the Json Array

```json
{
    "StID":"ST01",
    "StudentResults":[
        {
            "SubjectName":"Science",
            "SubjectMark":78
        },
                {
            "SubjectName":"Maths",
            "SubjectMark":65
        },
        {
            "SubjectName":"ICT",
            "SubjectMark":90
        }
    ],
    "ExamYear":"2022"
}
```

MySQl database table

[image: MySQL Table]

Comment: What is the type of `results.StudentResults`? And why do you expect that VS will know to convert it into a JSON string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results.StudentResults` is not of `string` type and your DB framework attempt to convert it to `string`, usually by using `ToString()` method available in all objects. You have to tell the program to convert it into JSON, see [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to):

```cs
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@StudentResults",
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(results.StudentResults));
```

`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 `` text is the default `ToString` behavior when you don't implement one yourself.

Comment: If I want to insert the json array data into separate columns in a mysql database, How can I do it? Thank You